# Can I insure a US visitor on my UK Vehicle?

Tags: uk, driving, insurance, driving-licenses, western-europe

I'm a UK Citizen and own a car registered and insured in the UK. I have a friend who is planning on visiting from the US, entering as a tourist. They have a US driving licence.

We would like to take a road trip through Europe; I'm insured to do this in my vehicle but we would like to share the driving. I have already emailed a help request to my insurance company to ask if I could add them as a temporary driver, however I don't hold out much hope as they say on their website:

> We can't amend your policy to cover a driver or vehicle on a temporary basis.

and

> You must have a valid UK or EU licence.
>   You must be a resident of Great Britain (not including Northern Ireland, the Isle of Man or the Channel Islands).

I have also tried some temporary insurance companies, but all seem to want a UK or EU Licence.

Are there any other options to allow my friend to drive my car, or should we be looking at rentals?

Comment: Visitors from everywhere...  I have done this lots of times, you just add them to the policy and cancel them at renewal time.  I did this for an American earlier this month, but have done nearly every country.

Comment: If the US friend maintains coverage, even if they don't own a car, their policy might (probably really) cover then while driving the OP's car.  They will have to contact their carrier to confirm.  Rarely, at least in the US, would one need to add a 'temporary' driver.

Comment: I've visited the UK often and been added to friends and family insurance. I've also added temporary drivers to my insurance when I was in the UK. You might consider changing your insurance company.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.hertsinsurance.com/walkabout/

> Cover valid throughout EU and other countries.
>
> Cover available for Campers including Vans Cover for periods ranging from 14 days to 1 year
>
> No permanent address needed - documents can be sent by e-mail
>
> Overseas driving license acceptable, including Australia, New Zealand, **USA**,  Canada, South Africa and other selected countries

Surely they can insure a normal car similarly.

Emphasis added to the USA by me -- it's quite rare, many will sell this [Aviva](http://www.aviva.co.uk/car-insurance/short-term-car-insurance/more-information/) policy which does not include the USA.

The Aviva link now (19-Jun-20) opens their quote page which takes you to the DayInsurance quote page which requires a UK or EU licence